# Microsft azure audio-to-speech API. Upload audio file and identify who is speaking

Tags: javascript

using Microsft azure audio-to-speech API. I upload the audio file and transcribe it well. However, I would like to know how to identify which person is talking. Or also know with which other api I can meet this objective

Comment: Take a look at Microsoft's documentation on Speaker Recognition.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speaker-recognition-overview

Comment: Yes, in the documentation it says that you have to register it speaking first. This in order to be able to identify it. However, in my case, it is long audio that I must convert; and gradually identify the speakers

Comment: Is it possible to get chunks of 20-second recording of each person from the audio file, and use them as profile sample?